# Find the points of inflexion of $f$ when $f '' (x) = (x-1) (x-3) (x-4)^2$

Tags: calculus

Given the second derivative, how do we find the points of inflexion?  The given answer states that $x=1$ and $x=3$ are points of inflexion, but not $x=4$.  I'm not sure why $x=4$ is not a point of inflexion.

---

Answer (score 2):

Points of inflection are where the second derivative changes sign. So $f''(x) < 0$ for "around" $x_0$ to the left and $f''(x) > 0$ around $x_0$ to the right (or the other way around). Since $f''(x)$ is continuous in your question, a necessary condition is also that $f''(x) = 0$.

The possible candidates are $x = 1, 3, 4$. What I find is helpful is to write what sign $f''(x)$ would be for each interval. For $x < 1$, $f''(x) > 0$. For $1 < x < 3$, $f''(x) < 0$. For $3 < x < 4$, $f''(x) > 0$. For $x > 4$, $f''(x) > 0$. So it only changes sign at $x = 1$ and $x = 3$.

The reason it doesn't change sign at $x = 4$ is that the $(x-4)^2$ term is always positive, so that term ends up making no difference in the sign of $f''(x)$.

Comment: That's clear, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're interested in finding points where $f''$ changes sign. Make a sign chart:

$$\begin{array}{c}
       &0 &  & 1 & & 2 & & 3 & & 4 &  & 5 & & 6\\
(x-1)  &- &- & 0 &+ &+ &+ &+ &+ &+ &+ &+ &+ &+\\
(x-3)  &- &- &- &- &- & - & 0 & + & + & +&+ &+ &+ \\
(x-4)^2&+ & + & + & + &+ &+ &+ &+ & 0 & + & +&+ &+  \\
(x-1)(x-3)(x-4)^2 &+ & + & 0 &- &- &-& 0 &+ &0 &+ &+& + & +
\end{array}
$$
So the product changes sign at $x=1$ and $x=3$, but not at $x=4$.

The reason is that  $(x-4)^2$ is always nonnegative for real $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Near $x = 4$, the $f''(x) \ge 0$ and it doesn't change sign from $+$ to $-$ or $-$ to $+$. So $x=4$ is not an inflection point. But at $x = 1,3$ the $f''(x)$ does change sign $-$ to $+$, hence they are the inflection points.

Answer (score 0):

As a [general rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)#Behavior_of_a_polynomial_function_near_a_multiple_root)  for any polynomial, its graph  crosses the x-axis if the multiplicity of the real root is **odd**, and  touches the x-axis if the multiplicity of the real root is **even**.

Apply this  to $f '' (x) = (x-1) (x-3) (x-4)^2$, the multiplicity of real root 4 is 2(an **even** number), so its curve is tangent to x axis at x=4,  $f''(x)$ does not change sign at this  root $x=4$ , we conclude  $x=4$ is not an inflection point.

[image]

Comment: Thinking of it in terms of multiplicity of real roots is a nice way to see it.